# Starting a section in a new page with "plain"-style with `amsart'

Tags: header-footer, page-breaking, amsart, pagestyle

With `amsart`, I am not able to force (but manually inserting `newpage` before thesection in question) an exceptional page style for a start of section. In the MWE below, I tried to force `plain`-style, but I cannot get it unless I also add manually a page-break. Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{amsart}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage{kantlipsum} 

\begin{document}

\title{Starting section in a page without header}

  \author[authors]{\small{Authors}}
\address{University of....
} 

\begin{abstract}
 \kant[2]
\end{abstract}

\maketitle 
\tableofcontents
 \kant[5]   

\thispagestyle{empty}

% I can force the plain-style
% if I uncomment next line:
% \newpage 
% but this is manually ... 
\section{Introduction}\thispagestyle{plain}\label{sec:intro} 

 \kant[6] 

\section{first sec}

 \kant[4] 
 \section{second sec}

  \kant[1] 

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that `\thispagestyle{plain}` is processed when TeX is still typesetting page 1 and, indeed, you get pagestyle `plain` in the first page. Only after having processed the `\section` command LaTeX realizes that a page break is necessary.

You can use `afterpage`.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} 

\begin{document}

\title{Starting section in a page without header}

\author[authors]{\small{Authors}}
\address{University of....} 

\begin{abstract}
 \kant[2]
\end{abstract}

\maketitle 
\tableofcontents

\kant[5]   

\thispagestyle{empty}

\afterpage{\thispagestyle{plain}}
\section{Introduction}\label{sec:intro} 

\kant[6] 

\section{first sec}

\kant[4] 

\section{second sec}

\kant[1] 

\end{document}
```

[image]